# Para que serve base.OnCreate(bundle) e o que é bundle?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

Estou começando com o Xamarin studio e queria saber para que serve essa classe "base", esse método `onCreate()` e o que é `bundle`?

Comment: Sua dúvida foi esclarecida jovem? Ou precisa de mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 5):

## onCreate()

Fazendo parte do [Clico de Vida da Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html?hl=pt-br), o `onCreate()` é o método responsável por carregar os *layouts* e outras operações de inicialização.
O ciclo de vida completo da *Activity* ocorre entre a primeira chamada no `onCreate(Bundle)` até a chamada do `onDestroy()`. Sendo assim, uma *Activity* irá executar tudo o que for "global" no `onCreate()` e liberar todos os recursos no `onDestroy()`. Este método mantem o estado da atividade antes dela ser encerrada.

## Bundle

De acordo a tradução para o português, significa "pacote", que são geralmente utilizados para a passagem de dados entre as várias atividades (`Activity`) do Android.

Detalhes

- [Activity – o que é isso?](http://www.felipesilveira.com.br/2010/05/activity-o-que-e-isso/)

Comment: +1 uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 3):

O método [onCreate()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnCreate/p/Android.OS.Bundle/) é um dos métodos do chamado [Ciclo de vida da Activity](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/).

*Activity* é uma classe que não deve ser instanciada directamente, deve se apenas criada pelo sistema *Android*, em resposta a um [Intent](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/).
Veja esse método como se fosse o construtor da classe.
Ele é chamado quando a *Activity* é criada. Nele deve ser colocado a parte do código referente à sua inicialização, nomeadamente a atribuição do *layout*, via `setContentView()`, a ser utilizado por ela.

A implementação da classe obriga que as classes derivadas, ao implementarem(*overrride*) o método `onCreate()`, chamem a sua implementação na classe "mãe", `super.onCreate()` é isso mesmo.

[Bundle](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.Bundle/) representa um conjunto de pares "chave/valor".
Permite guardar valores de qualquer tipo primitivo ou que implementem a interface [IParcelable](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.IParcelable/). Ele é comummente usado no *Android* para passar valores entre componentes.

No contexto do método `onCreate()` é usado para recuperar os valores guardados no método [OnSaveInstanceState()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnSaveInstanceState/p/Android.OS.Bundle/).

Uma *Activity* pode, a qualquer momento, ser destruída e recriada, por exemplo, quando há uma rotação do dispositivo.
Antes de destruir a *Activity*, o *Android* chama o método `OnSaveInstanceState()`, passando a ele um argumento do tipo *Bundle* para que possa ser utilizado para guardar quaisquer valores, entre eles os que definem o estado actual da *Activity*.
Esse *Bundle* é depois passado ao método `onCreate()`, quando a *Activity* é recriada, dando a possibilidade de usar os valores guardados para a inicializar no estado que tinha antes de ser destruída.

Answer (score 2):

[`onCreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) é executado quando uma `Activity` é criada. Geralmente é o método responsável por carregar os layouts (XML) e outras operações de inicialização. Só é executado uma vez durante o Clico de Vida da `Activity`.

O [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) é uma classe usada para guardar objetos na forma de pares chave/valor. O `Bundle` é usado para passar dados entre componentes Android através da classe `Intent`.

O método `onCreate` recebe um parâmetro do tipo `Bundle`, ele é responsável por guardar o estado da `Activity` quando ela é reiniciada, como se fosse um cache.